# CSS error checking styled components in Visual Studio Code

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio-code, styled-components

Is there a solution (plugin, package, etc.) to get real CSS error checking in Visual Studio Code, when using styled components?

The code example below is an error (I know that), but I would like to know of a tooling solution for Visual Studio Code that shows that. The regular linter setup does not catch that.

I have a linter installed, which catches syntax error, but what about "Invalid property values" like the following:

```
const StyledSubHitElDiv = styled.div`
  display: down
`;
```

I could not find anything and since I have already installed *[Stylelint](https://stylelint.io/)* and *[vs-code-styled-components](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components)*, I believe I have the normal setup running.

Comment: "Invalid property values" so your property display has an invalid value. Down is not a correct value for display. So this is a real error checking.

Comment: I know, that it is an error. I just want to know of a linter/vs-code-extension, that shows me this as an error before runtime

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the same thing today.
I was using [Stylelint](https://stylelint.io/) via the
[vscode-stylelint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stylelint.vscode-stylelint) extension and was wondering why it doesn't catch the type of errors you're describing above.

On the Stylelint GitHub page, I discovered a [discussion on this topic](https://github.com/stylelint/stylelint/issues/3343) where one of the Stylelint developers recommends using the [stylelint-csstree-validator](https://github.com/csstree/stylelint-validator).

I tried it out, and it works as expected. Really nice!

Answer (score 0):

I installed IntelliJ IDEA and the invalid value has the error underline to fix for both [SCSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29) and CSS.

*vscode-csstree* works only for CSS.

[image]

Comment: Why IntelliJ when this question is tagged with Visual Studio Code?

Comment: This is close to incomprehensible (due to use of machine translation). Can you fix it, please?